# SQLite3 with Ruby, Cannot Search Resulting Array (iterates over array as if it were one giant element)

Tags: ruby, parsing, sqlite

I've been trying to find an answer for a little while now, and I'm not sure if I'm asking the wrong questions, but I've had no luck so far.

I have an array generated from querying an SQLite table. I also have an array of times generated from a csv file. I am trying to pull the time[0] (an id number) and check if it exists in the array from the SQL table

```
array = []
SQLite3::Database.new("t.db") do |db|
    db.execute ("SELECT t FROM ts") do |row|
        array << row
    end
end

times = CSV.read('times1.csv')

times.each do |time|
    #puts "This is the trip id: #{time[0]}"
    if array.include? time[0]
        puts time[0]
        end
end
```

When I do this, I get no results. I know for a fact that there should be a few matches. When I try to iterate over the array like:

```
array.each do |row|
    if row = 2345
         puts "Match found"
    end
end
```

Here is the strange part that has really stumped me. I know that 2345 only comes up once or twice in the array, however when I run this code, it seems as though it prints "Match found" for every element (like 5,000 times it says "Match found"). I feel like something is wrong with the array generated from the SQLite but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In here:

```
db.execute ("SELECT t FROM ts") do |row|
```

your `row` is an array whose sole element is the `t` you're after. That means that you end up with an array-of-arrays in `array` rather than an array of numbers and of course your `array.include? time[0]` check fails because `array` only contains other arrays.

You probably want to say:

```
array << row[0]
```

to collect the `t` values in `array`.